# R: How to fill geom_hex with a numerical value and heat scale it?

Tags: r

I was wondering how I can scale geom_hex not on count, but rather by a variable and heat scale it? I am also having overfitting in my actual model and was wondering how to eliminate that? Here's an examples:

```
 '''
  ggplot(data = diamonds)+
  geom_hex(mapping = aes(x = x, y = price, fill = depth, bins = 
  25))+
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis")
 '''
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick, assuming you want to colour the hexagons according to the mean of `depth`...

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = x, y = price, z = depth)) +
  stat_summary_hex(fun = mean, bins = 25) +
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis")
```

[image]